# MYSQLI Extension not working with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, server, mamp

I am getting this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

When trying to run a simple php script.

PHPinfo shows no MYSQLI but the CORRECT php.conf file has both these lines UNcommented

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

So i have mysqli as far as I know.

I tried uncommenting all other extensions which didnt work.

Any ideas how to fix this?

## EDIT:

Turning on display Errors triggers MYSQLI extension to go away.
What could this mean?

Comment: This is version 7.1.5

Comment: Do you use MAMP on your server? Or why do you use the tag here? Normally when you use MAMP that extensions are installed by default.

Comment: what does `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));` output?

Comment: Please verify in your php.ini, if the extension directory is set to correct path. Also you can explicitly specify path for your extensions:

`extension=C:\Php\php-???-nts-Win32-VC11-x86\ext\php_mysql.dll`

Comment: I am using MAMP servers.
The extensions are in the correct .ini file and uncommented.

I uninstalled and reinstalled MAMP and it worked
 BUT when i turned display Errors on - MYSQLI dissappeared again!
Just Recommented Display ERRORS and Hey presto MYSQLI is back.
What is going on!

Comment: I cant say what var_dump shows as if I have display errors on it wont show a webpage

Comment: Jash Parekh How/where do i set the explicit extension path?

Comment: Any update on why turning on Display Errors in PHP MAMP deactivates my mysqli extension?